# MediaElement Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am displaying list of songs on listbox i have bind media element but i am Unable  to get media element name instance in songs.cs file and unable to play song

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <MediaElement Name="Player"  Source="{Binding SongUrl}" AutoPlay="False"/>
                                 <Button  Name="Click" Click="Play_Click"  Content="Button"/>
                                <StackPanel Width="150" Height="50">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"  TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red"  FontSize="16"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

example in Songs.cs:

```
  private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Player.play(); (unable to get Media Element name) 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The media player should not be inside the ItemTemplate since you will be playing only one sound at a time I believe (it would be costly to have a media element for eaach item). So you should move the MEdiaaPlayer outside and on button click do:

```
private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button button=sender as Button;
   Player.Source=((Item)button.DataContext).SongUrl
  Player.play(); (unable to get Media Element name) 
}
```

Comment: Player.Source=((Item)button.DataContext).SongUrl  what dose Item mean

Comment: You need to replace Item by whatever class SongUrl is in, since I didn't have the class name i just put a temporary name